# Add additional column of average of multiple entries of same items using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Fruits': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Orange'],
        'Price': [100, 300, 250, 300, 80, 150],
        'Amount': [ 2, 5,  5,  10, 10, 8]
    }
)

# Display DataFrame
print(df)


#df1 = df.groupby(['Fruits'], as_index=False).agg({'Price': 'sum', 'Amount': 'sum'})
#print(df1)


df1 = df.groupby(['Fruits'],as_index=False).sum()
print(df1)

def f(x):    
  return x[1]/x[2]

df1['Average'] = df1.apply(f, axis=1)
print(df1)
```

Like in the above example, can I create an additional column of average price values of the same 'Fruits' without invoking a function?

Comment: Do you mean `df1['Average'] = df1['Price'] / df1['Amount']`? Or did you mean in a single step directly from `df`?

Comment: Perhaps from `df` where I'm using `groupby`.

Answer (score 2):

Data:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
>>>     {
>>>         'Fruits': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Orange'],
>>>         'Price': [100, 300, 250, 300, 80, 150],
>>>         'Amount': [ 2, 5,  5,  10, 10, 8]
>>>     }
>>> )
>>> df1 = df.groupby(['Fruits'],as_index=False).sum()
>>> df1
    Fruits  Price   Amount
0   Apple   650     12
1   Banana  80      10
2   Orange  450     18
```

If you need just one variable, you can do simply `df1['Average'] = df1.Price/df1.Amount` if you need multiple variables you can use 'assign'

```
>>> df1 = df1.assign(Average   = lambda x:x.Price / x.Amount, 
                     Average_2 = lambda x:x.Price / x.Amount
)
>>> df1

    Fruits  Price   Amount  Average    Average_2
0   Apple   650     12      54.166667  54.166667
1   Banana  80      10      8.000000   8.000000
2   Orange  450     18      25.000000  25.000000
```

Comment: Why need to use relatively more complicated syntax, if you can already use `df1['Average'] = df1['Price'] / df1['Amount']` as mentioned in the comment ?